# getting error DBI_DRIVER env var not set while running dbicdump

Tags: sqlite, perl, dbix-class, dbd

I was testing to dump the `DBIx::Class` for my sample sqlite database on the windows 7 machine.
I have installed `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` , along with `DBI` and `DBD::SQLite` module , but when I am using the script `dbicdump` it giving the below error

```
C:\Users\Foo\Documents\dbDump>perl dbicdump.pl dump_directory=.\lib ^
More?     -o components="[q{InflateColumn::DateTime}]" ^
More?     -o preserve_case=1 ^
More?     MyApp::Schema DBI::SQLite:./sqlite.db

DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::catch {...} (): DBI Connection failed: Can't   connect
to data source 'MyApp::Schema' because I can't work out what driver to use (it 
doesn't seem to contain a 'dbi:driver:' prefix and the DBI_DRIVER env var is not
set) at C:/Perl64/site/lib/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI.pm line 1517. at dbicdump.pl 
line 178
```

I tried googling it out but was not able to find any appropriate for to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `dbicdump` has got slightly confused when parsing your command line options. It thinks that `MyApp::Schema` is the connection information, not `DBI::SQLite:./sqlite.db`.

I suspect that's because you have missed the `-o` that should go before the `dump_directory=.\lib` option.